# Fi-ware 503 - Service unavailable

Tags: fiware-orion

We are getting this 503 HTTP response:

```
'Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)'
```

when we request: http://orion.lab.fi-ware.org:1026/v1/queryContext?limit=1000

It goes on and off, for instance, this is extracted from the logs yesterday:

```
14:55 – 15:39 -> 503 responses
15:51 – 16:21 -> 503 responses
15:36 – 16:50 -> 503 responses
16:55 – 16:58 -> 503 responses
17:33 – 18:37 -> 503 responses
19:16 – 19:21 -> 503 responses
20:01 – 20:13 -> 503 responses
20:52 – 21:03 -> 503 responses
21:16 – 23:26 -> 503 responses
05:04 – 05:07 -> 503 responses
```

We are making the request once every minute, and in those periods, every single request was a 503 and outside those, everything worked just fine.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Yesterday, there was some unstability that seem to be solved now. Could you try again and tell how it goes, please?

Comment: Thank you! seems to be solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orion global instance at orion.lab.fiware.org suffered some instability problems on November 17th and 18th. However, they seem to be solved now.

These temporal glitches use to happen from time to time, but they don't use to long too much. However, note that although FIWARE staff do their best to keep this instance up and stable, take into account [the following disclaimer at Orion entry in the the FIWARE Catalogue](http://catalogue.fiware.org/enablers/publishsubscribe-context-broker-orion-context-broker/instances):

> Take into account that this is a global instance shared among all its users That means that your actions on the instance could impact to other users or viceversa. In this sense, this instance is fine to do prospective testing and to analyse the feasibility of the GEi to your purposes. However, if you are planing to use this GEi in production, please consider to deploy a dedicated instance for you in the FIWARE cloud.